# Socket.io with Amazon Load Balancer, what ports should be forwarded?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, socket.io, load-balancing, ports

I have some socket.io node.js servers running as amazon instances, when connecting directly to an instance, my socket.io application can connect and reconnect in a few milliseconds. However, when I direct the application through the load balancer, the application is a lot slower to connect and reconnect (taking 5+ seconds).

I have configured the load balancer to forward TCP port 80, as well as well the port that my node servers listen on (port 3000). Are there any other ports required by socket.io to function optimally? Or is my issue caused by something other than ports?

Thanks.

Comment: do you mind sharing how you do your load balancing. You have a load balancer fronting your nodejs instances. socketio is on another instance, and accessing nodejs through the load balancer? In this case, did yo.u load balance socket.io as well?

Comment: Not quite, at the moment my applications are loaded on a separate PHP server and are not load balanced. The socket.io server is behind a load balancer. I only need push messages to go **to** the client and not **from**, therefore a client will be directed to an available server, and when I push out messages, they will be pushed to all instances / servers. Hope that explains it a bit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've realised that this isn't to do with ports or anything like that. The amazon load balancer keeps the first reconnection attempt open until it times out, this means that the first connection waits 60 seconds before timing out or reconnecting. I have not been able to reduce the timeout on the ELB, this is a known issue on the AWS forums and has been for a few **years** now.